# Cannot receive parameter from Script content to Predefined Parameter in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to pass hostname parameter which is declared at **Script Content** to **Predefined Parameter in Trigger/calls on build other project** where my child project will receive parameter from the parent project.My code looks like this in Script Content:

```
`machine_name="$(hostname)"`
```

So in order to pass my parameter to the child project  I declared:

`host_name=${machinename}`

in Script Content .But when I check in my child project it display as **${machinename}** which is not I want .Can someone tell me what am I missing or what step that I done wrong or is there any way to perform this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [ENv Inject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), all you need to do is below:

Your script should contain below step:

```
machine_name="$(hostname)" > inject.txt
```

Now use Inject environment variables build step and in

> property file path give inject.txt

what's the use?

By this step, now you machine_name variable holds the hostname value throughout the job.

Next, in your Parameter in Trigger/calls on build other project

```
host_name=${machine_name}
```

And use the same variable in child job.

I think there is no need for multiple assignments above, but still you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

'_' was missing. `host_name=$machine_name`. 
you cannot set or pass the parameter value from the script o/p.  either make it as env variable using groovy or set in to property file & read.

Comment: Sorry for the typo , assuming that I add the _ for host_name =${machine_name} it will pass ${machinename} as a string in the child job and based on [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Environment+Script+Plugin) it stated that the output produced will be evaluated as environment variable .So I am not sure whats wrong with that .

Comment: Create a string variable (host_name) in second job. it will get values from (parameterized trigger plugin) value from first job.